# bot framework use luis - how to send a single request to luis

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

i'm new with luis and bot framework. what i learned until now is how to trigger a dialog by an intent recognized by luis. but i don't know how to send a message to luis inside a dialog. i want to use the 'builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity' method. i'm pretty sure that my builder.prompts.text just gives me the pure text as a result, not the intents and entities of this text recognized by LUIS. but i can't find a solution how i can send a single request to luis, to get back a luis-json object which i think is needed for the 'findEntity' method.

```
bot.dialog('reklamation',[
function(session){
    session.send('Gerne kümmere ich mich um Ihre Reklamation.');
    builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Bitte nennen Sie mir Ihr Anliegen.');
},
function(session, results){
    session.dialogData.reklamation = results.response;
    session.send('Ich habe Ihre Mitteilung aufgenommen.');
    builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Bitte geben Sie mir eine E-Mail-Adresse, unter der wir Ihnen den aktuellen Stand Ihrer Reklamation mitteilen können.');
},
function(session, results){
    var email = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(results.entities, 'email');
    session.dialogData.email = email;
    session.send('Ok! Ich habe folgende Informationen gespeichert:');
    session.send('Reklamationsgrund: ' + session.dialogData.reklamation);
    session.send('E-Mail: ' + session.dialogData.email);
    session.endDialog('Wir werden uns schnellstmöglich mit Ihnen in Verbindung setzen. Vielen Dank für Ihre Anfrage!');
}]).triggerAction({
matches: 'reklamation'});
```

I appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entities are retrieved in the first step of the waterfall. The intent is basically defined in the matches. So your code will be triggered if your LUIS app has a intent "reklamation"

Then you need to update the signature of the first function to:

```
bot.dialog('reklamation', [
    function (session, args, next) {
```

Then you can use:

```
builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.intent.entities, 'email');
```

If what you are looking is to call LUIS manually after the first step of the waterfall, you can try with:

```
builder.LuisRecognizer.recognize("your input", modelUrl, (err, intents, entities) { ... }
```

Take a look at the [LUIS Node.js sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS) for more information.

Comment: So that means all i can not use luis to recognize a new message inside a dialog?
my plan is the following (short text example inside the chatbot):

me: I have a problem!

bot(luis detects problem and starts the problem dialog):please tell me your email adress.

me: my e-mail-adress is abc@gmail.com

bot(should recognize abc@gmail.com as an entity): okay! i've recognized the following mail-adress: 'abc@gmail.com'. please describe your problem ... ... ...

but for the last point i need a luis recognition.

Comment: No at all, I probably misunderstood your question. There are 2 options: 1) call luis manually 2) try the following `builder.LuisRecognizer.recognize(actionModel.userInput, modelUrl, (err, intents, entities) {`

Comment: No problem. I write english like i write german. Maybe I just didn't write clearly enough. but that's exactly what i wanted to know. how can i call luis manually? you helped me a lot until here. if you can explain this to me you'll be my all time hero... at least for 2 weeks. :)

Comment: have you tried the line of code I sent n the previous comment?

Comment: sorry, school was out yesterday. i tried your code line now and it worked out really great. thanks a lot!!! :)